# Laravel 5 php DOMdocument

Tags: php, dom, laravel-5.1

Ive been trying to find a way to use php DOMdocument in laravel 5.1 but I fail every time. I think I don't get how it works.

I need to get title and/or video ID from youtube page, or any other page.

Ive tried to include this [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

and other things.
But I always get server 500 error and don't know why.

Currently I have

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ7XJG0Z2ho');
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

And on my view I just do

```
@if(isset($a))
    {{var_dump($a)}}
@endif
```

It returns

```
object(DOMNodeList)#171 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
```

But this is not the title. Don't even know what this means.
Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong or maybe there is better way to do it?

Comment: If you get a 500 error you should start looking the webserver error logs to discover the details of the error

Comment: I don't get the 500 error anymore. I just don't get what it returns, I ask for a title and I get `object(DOMNodeList)#171 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }`

Answer (score 4):

Using [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ7XJG0Z2ho');
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

Using [`loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ7XJG0Z2ho');
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

Using URL opening within `load()` or `loadHTMLfile()` methods needs `allow_url_fopen` directive enable in ini file.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen = On` is on on my vagrant VM, but it still gives me `object(DOMNodeList)#171 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) }` when I use `var_dump($a)` and this is not the title. Is there a way i can use innerHTML like in javascript?

Comment: `$a->item(0)->nodeValue` will give you text inside title tag. You can't directly use a `$url` within `loadHTML()`, you should use `file_get_contents()` in order to do that. @MarijnRutten